# Error in lag.listw, object lengths differ

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, spatial

I am estimating a fixed-effects model on spatial panel data using the R package "splm". The strongly balanced panel consists of 77 counties and 31 years of observations. The dependent variable is county-wise yields of one crop. When I regress yield over time trend and individual fixed-effects, I get the error that object lengths differ, even though I have perfectly balanced panel and the same set of counties are used to create the spatial weight matrix.

Below I have generated a "panel data set" resembling my data, and also generated the longitude and latitude data for the counties with random numbers. Even with this random data, the same error occurs.

```
##generated panel data for yield
set.seed(97531)
yield.normal <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2387*1, mean=1.92, sd=0.5), ncol=1))
colnames(yield.normal) = "yield"
yield.normal$panelid = with(yield.normal, seq(1:77))
yield.normal$timeid = with(yield.normal, seq(1:31))
yield.normal$county = with(yield.normal, as.factor(seq(1:77)))
yield.normal$countyname = paste0("county",yield.normal$county)
yield.normal$trnd = with(yield.normal, seq(1:31))

#generate coordinates of the 77 Oklahoma counties
latitude.county = sample(36.83013180:33.90212700, size = 77, replace = T)
longitude.county = sample(-94.81059550:-102.62162110, size = 77, replace = T)
lat.long.data = cbind2(longitude.county,latitude.county)
colnames(lat.long.data)=c("lon","lat")
#Create spatial weight matrix
distNeighbr = spdep::dnearneigh(lat.long.data, d1=0, d2=5)
wtmat1 = spdep::nb2listw(distNeighbr, style='W')

#Estimate the spatial fixed-effects model
spatial.FE.model = splm::spml(yield~trnd, data = yield.normal, index = c("timeid", "panelid"), listw = wtmat1,  model = "within", effect ="individual", method = "eigen")
```

Error report:

```
Error in lag.listw(listw, u, zero.policy = zero.policy) : object
lengths differ
```

Output from: `traceback()` is as follows:

```
8: stop("object lengths differ")

7: lag.listw(listw, u, zero.policy =zero.policy)

6: FUN(X[[i]], ...)

5: lapply(X = ans[index], FUN = FUN,...)

4: tapply(y, inde, function(u) lag.listw(listw, u, zero.policy
=zero.policy), simplify = TRUE)

3: unlist(tapply(y, inde, function(u) lag.listw(listw, u, zero.policy
zero.policy), simplify = TRUE))

2: spfeml(formula = formula, data = data, index = index, listw =
listw,  listw2 = listw2, na.action, model = model, effects = effects,
cl = cl, ...)

1: splm::spml(yield ~ trnd + as.factor(county) - 1, data =
yield.normal, index = c("timeid", "panelid"), listw = wtmat1, model =
"within", effect = "individual", method = "eigen")
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. The authors of the package "splm" pointed out that there was a mistake in the way the panel ids were set up. The spatial units must be slower (1,1,1,.....; 2,2,2...;....;77,77,77,....) and the time id must be faster (1,2,3,....,31;....; 1,2,3...31) of the two. After setting up the data accordingly, I could get the results.

Sincere thanks to the "splm" authors Drs. Giovanni Millo and Gianfranco Piras.